# Install Mountain Lion with a different Apple ID

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using my office mac.

Mac App store and iCloud settings all map to my personal apple ID.

Now since it is not my personal mac, I would need my office to pay for the Mountain Lion upgrade. Can I temporarily signin to Mac App store using my boss's credentials, upgrade to Lion and then sign out back to use my personal apple ID.

So then the OS would have been installed under one AppleID and the apps & updates will be under my apple ID. Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will. Apple only checks during the Setup and the purchasing for which iTunes (Apple ID) account is associated with the operating system and purchase

Comment: Don't forget to up vote as well